# Zoom API request with OAuth in PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, zoom-sdk

I'm trying to make a simple API request to Zoom API - to insert a registrant to a webinar.
As I know, I need to get OAuth key and then make a second call to insert a registrant to a webinar.
I got an error:

> "OAuth Request Failed: 400 {"reason":"unsupported grant type","error":"unsupported_grant_type"}"

Here is an explanation that can help:

https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/reference/zoom-api/methods/#operation/webinarRegistrantCreate

https://developers.zoom.us/docs/internal-apps/s2s-oauth/

Here is my code (I hide the API Key, the Secret Key and the account id):

```
class Zoom_Api
{

    public function getToken() {
        $url = 'https://zoom.us/oauth/token';
        $data = array(
        'grant_type' => 'account_credentials',
        'account_id' => '*******'
        );
        
        $zoomAPIKey  = '************';
        $zoomSecretKey  = '************';

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($zoomAPIKey.":".$zoomSecretKey)
        );
        
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);


        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($httpCode == 200) {
            // Parse the JSON response to get the access token
            $oauthResponse = json_decode($response, true);
            $accessToken = $oauthResponse['access_token'];
            return $accessToken;
        } else {
            echo 'OAuth Request Failed: ' . $httpCode . PHP_EOL;
            echo $response . PHP_EOL;
            return null;
        }
        
        curl_close($curl);
    }


    public function sentRequest() {
        $name = "testdfdf";
        $email = "sdfd@dfdfdfdf.com";
        $webinarID = 867098960000;

        $regData = array(
        'email' => $email,
        'first_name' => $name,

        );

        $jsonStrReg = json_encode($regData);
        $httpStrReg = http_build_query($regData);
        
        $ch = curl_init('https://api.zoom.us/v2/webinars/'.$webinarID.'/registrants');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $httpStrReg);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->getToken()
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $response = json_decode($response);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
    }


}


$zoom_meeting = new Zoom_Api();
$response = $zoom_meeting->getToken();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "<pre>";
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I haven't used the API yet, but the documentation states that you should include your account_id in the POST body.

Comment: I added this to the request (see updated code) but still same error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problems: I created the wrong app type on Zoom and the request data type is missing in the second request.